# tastypie overid create_response() method

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I tring to override tastypie `create_response` because I have some verification to do before sending response to user. this is my code:

```
class MyNamespacedModelResource(NamespacedModelResource):
    def create_response(self , request , data):
        r = super(MyNamespacedModelResource , self).create_response(request , data , response_class=HttpResponse)
            # ... some treatements...
        return r
```

And I have user NamespaceModelResource who work fine before.

When I tring to add new user ( with post method) , I have got this

```
error:

create_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'response_class'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the method `create response()` with two positional arguments. However, the super class definition looks like this:

```
def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs)
```

Why this is a problem is that your overridden method is called with keyword arguments that you haven't "accepted" in your definition. That's what the `**response_kwargs` stands there for. It means this function can have an infinite number of keyword args. Your definition can have 0. So if you change your definition to either `create_response(self, request, data, **kwargs)` or `create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs)`, you'll be rid of this problem. But you'll have another one on your hands. In 99% of the cases, keyword arguments must be passed on to the super class method. So the ideal version in most cases is to just duplicate both the definition and `super()` method call, which in your case looks like this:

```
class MyNamespacedModelResource(NamespacedModelResource):
    def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
        r = super(MyNamespacedModelResource , self).create_response(request, data, response_class=response_class, **response_kwargs)

        return r
```